# Get the content height of a UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, height, uitextview

I use this open source library called [ReadMoreTextView](https://github.com/ilyapuchka/ReadMoreTextView) to display a bunch of text. The library enables me to toggle between displaying an excerpt of the text and showing the full length content (the button is a normal UIButton added by me, not the library).

[image]
[image]

This works as expected.

My problem arises when I have to display a smaller amount of text. If I add some content that doesn't exceed the height of the UITextView, I want to hide the more/less toggle button. So I thought of taking the full content height and if only it's larger than the text view's height, show the toggle button.

In the above example, I aded a long couple of paragraphs that exceeds the text view bounds. The text view's height comes up as 128. But the content height also returns 128. There's a library specific method called `boundingRectForCharacterRange` which is supposed to return the content height also returns a wrong value (100).

```
print("TEXTVIEW HEIGHT: \(textView.bounds.height)") // 128
print("CONTENT HEIGHT: \(textView.contentSize.height)") // 128

let rect = textView.layoutManager.boundingRectForCharacterRange(range: NSRange(location: 0, length: textView.text.count), inTextContainer: textView.textContainer)
print("TEXT HEIGHT: \(rect.height)") // 100
```

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/ilyapuchka/ReadMoreTextView/issues/40) at the library's Github page but the owner asked to ask it here.

Why does the content height return a wrong value?

Here is the [project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bke1k93n6mp9vlo/TextTrim.zip?dl=0) I'm using in the above example by the way.

Comment: Could you use a `UILabel`; ergo, is the text read-only? It seem that this behaviour should be easy to implement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply use following method to get the content size:

```
let contentSize = self.textView.sizeThatFits(self.textView.bounds.size)
```

Then update the textview frame accordingly:

```
self.textView.frame = CGRect(width: contentSize.width, height: contentSize.height)
```